# How does Archimedes principle explain the principle of immiscible liquids?

Tags: fluid-statics

> Archimedes' principle (also spelled Archimedes's principle) states that the upward buoyant force that is exerted on a body immersed in a fluid, whether fully or partially, is equal to the weight of the fluid that the body displaces.

But in a system which contains 2 immiscible liquids, there is no scope of immersion of the less dense liquid. Does Archemides' principle work for this system?

Answer (score 0):

There is no displacement of the heavier fluid, so Archimedes principle does not apply. But the pressure at the top of the heavier fluid in increased by the weight of the overlaying lighter fluid and this upward pressure counters the weight of the lighter fluid plus the pressure (say atmospheric) at the top of the lighter fluid.